# RelativeLayout android:gravity not use below api 16?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I write to show a video's name and mark.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drama_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#ff9313"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="8.8"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drama_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:gravity="left|end"
            android:textColor="#ff323232"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="See you again"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/drama_mark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But it not use below android 16.Why it show in right?The video, name maybe two or more lines.I have try many times ,please help me.
[image]

Comment: You want to show on left side?

Comment: Gravity existed well before 16.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I want drama_mark int the right of drama_name,and drama_name maybe many lines.

Comment: @GabeSechan But it doesn't show what I want. It work well after 16

Comment: Use android:layout_width="match_parent" for your drama_name

Comment: @Sree14 I want the drama_mark int the right of drama_name,but not in the right of the relativelayout.

Comment: see my updated answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drama_mark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textColor="#ff9313"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="8.8"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drama_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:gravity="left|start"
    android:textColor="#ff323232"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drama_mark"
    android:text="See you again gbfayufbafubsayfbas fysgafysaf fyasgfysuafas" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but it not work below api 16 when drama_name is short

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use `TableLayout` to solve my question.

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/distance"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drama_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#ff323232"
            android:text="see you again"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drama_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#ff9313"
            android:textSize="@dimen/big_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="8.8" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```